# How to pass variable entities to a generic function?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-plus

If i generate my entities through [Entity Framework Database First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx), and i want to use a function like that:

```
AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.Exclude<T>();
```

considering that the number of times i want to call it should be equal to the number of entities

ex:

```
AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.Exclude<Employee>();

AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.Exclude<Department>();

AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.Exclude<Room>();
```

---

Now how to Loop through selected number of entities and pass every one to the `Exclude` function ?

Comment: You are not passing entities to the generic function, you are passing **entity-types** to the generic function.

Comment: @Maarten : U are right , how to create list of entity types and passing the items to the generic function ?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem, what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Maarten : it try the following `List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
            types.Add(typeof(Employee));` but cann't use `types[0]` as function parameter

Comment: @DavidG : i want to control the entities which should be excluded through that function, The admin user should select set of entities and i want to pass those entities to `exclude function` to exclude them from auditing

Comment: So you want to stop Entity Framework from selecting certain rows from your data store? It's not very clear

Comment: @DavidG : No, i use `https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus` to audit my entities and this API has an `exclude` function, i want to pass specific entities to this function according to admin selection(data entry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious solution would be to call the method for every entity-type you want to hide. Like this:

```
AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.Exclude<Employee>();
AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.Exclude<Department>();
AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.Exclude<Room>();
```

You can add conditional statements (`if`s) around them to do it dynamically.

Howevery, if you want a fully flexible solution, where you call the `Exclude` method based on metadata, you need something else. Something like this:

```
var types = new[] { typeof(Employee), typeof(Department), typeof(Room) };
var instance = AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration;
var openGenericMethod = instance.GetType().GetMethod("Exclude");
foreach (var @type in types)
{
    var closedGenericMethod = openGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(@type);
    closedGenericMethod.Invoke(instance, null);
}
```

This assumes that the `Exclude<T>` method is an instance method on whatever instance `DefaultConfiguration` points to.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to looping through your entity types is to make the entities you don't want audited implement the same interface and exclude that. For example:

```
public interface IExcludeFromAudit
{ }
```

And your entities:

```
public class Order : IExcludeFromAudit
{
    //snip
}
```

And now just exclude the interface:

```
AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.Exclude<IExcludeFromAudit>();
```

The benefit of this is that it's now easy to control which ones are excluded.